# c# Random number from weighted average of values

Tags: c#, random

I'd like to take a range of four random integers between 1-64, and generate a random value somewhere within the range but leaning towards a more weighted average.

The practical application is that you take a pixel, grab the 4 surrounding pixels and use those plus the current pixel to generate a value that can then be used as the base weight for a Gaussian random number generator.  So you have a pixel of 10 brightness, surrounded by 8,8,9,9.  Add them all up, average out to 8.8.  8.8 is then the weight for the Gaussian random number generator.  So you have a random result within a range, but close to the average brightness which is 8.8, and still with some element of randomness.

The issue comes when you have wide variations because of random noise.

To give a pseudo example of how I would like it to work..

Input = [1,16,19,21]

The average of this is 14.25, but that has too much movement because of the "1" bringing the average way down.  The average of this should be more around the 18 mark, because more of the numbers are clustered around that area.

I would like to see a random result coming out that is between 1 and 64, but heavily weighted between 15 and 22, with a lower possibility of it being towards the 1(Because it is still within the range as a whole) and a much lower possibility of it being over 22(Because that is completely outside of the range).

**Additional** The purpose of this is to generate a galactic map.  I have got to the point where I have a good set of galaxy shaped data, giving me the rough density of each sector on the map.  Now I need to generate specific sets of data and generate exact numbers of stars in each sector.  Taking the average of the 4 surrounding sectors and using that to work out how "dense" this sector should be is the main purpose.  The main thing I want to avoid is that sectors bordering an empty region of space do not also end up mostly empty, as this does not fit with general observations of galaxies.

Comment: I think you'll need to define your problem better - i.e. should the probability of returning '18' be the highest because it is right on the average, or should it favour returning a random number actually in the provided set etc. If it doesn't favour the numbers from the set - i.e. the set is just provided for deviation/ spread/ average info - then compute those values first. What is this for?

Comment: Is the graph not enough to explain what I am expecting out?  I thought that seemed the best way to explain it.

Comment: Luke - Added that I expect the output to be between 1 and 64, I didn't realise I missed it out! :)

Comment: There's no explanation of what the numbers actually represent - it's difficult to work with a spread when you don't know anything about the numbers themselves (i.e. you could use a trimmed mean, which just dumps outliers, but that might not be appropriate). Also e.g. why are there 4, how come the graph isn't symmetric (i.e. on your graph, 30+ has 0 probability) etc.

Comment: The algorithm you ran in your head when you drew that graph is what you need to convert into code, but there seems to be rules that aren't described in your question (like why your graph drops off sharply on the right). So, simply defining more about what it is you're actually trying to do might be all you need to even answer your own question :)

Comment: I'll do a new graph, it isn't great.  Added to the description as well...

Comment: Removed the graph, the description is actually better.

Comment: Great that context helps a lot - As a general future tip, always frame your question in the context of the actual problem you're trying to solve, because people have often encountered similar cases. Example: I've generated galaxies using C# before (but I did it a very different way to this). My immediate thought is your approach is an unstable algorithm - the outcome depends on the outcome of neighbouring sectors. If you've already got galaxy-shaped data then you might be overthinking it (i.e. multiply it by some kind of density factor and just a pseudo-random number).

Comment: @LukeBriggs, thanks for the guidance, problem has been solved!

Comment: no problem! It would be great if you could add an answer (and accept it) so people are aware it has been answered/ if there's any info you can share with others who have this kind of question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could imagine that the four numbers are points in a line, the x axis. Around that points there is a sphere of probability with a radius of 64, with the probability more concentrated in the proximity of the points rather than on the edges. Pick randomly one of the four points, calculate a random point inside the sphere of that number and take its x coordinate. Repeat if it is out of the range 1..64.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ProbabilityDistribution1
{

    class Program
    {

        // This derived class converts the uniformly distributed random 
        // numbers generated by base.Sample( ) to another distribution.
        class RandomProportional : Random
        {
            // The Sample method generates a distribution more concentrated around the 0, in the range [0.0, 1.0].
            protected override double Sample()
            {
                double BSample = base.Sample();
                const double concentrationAroundInputs = 5;//more concentrated when greater
                double result = Math.Pow(BSample, concentrationAroundInputs);
                return result;
            }

        }

        static double XCoordinateOfRandomUnitInsideSphere(Random aRandom)
        {
            //Even with uniform distribution the probability of exiting is greater than 0.5 on each iteration
            while (true) 
            {
                double x = aRandom.NextDouble();
                double y = aRandom.NextDouble();
                double z = aRandom.NextDouble();
                if ((x * x + y * y + z * z) < 1) //inside the sphere
                {
                    return x;
                }
            }

        }

        static void TestDistribution()
        {

            double[] Input = { 1, 16, 19, 21 };
            List<int> sampleValues = new List<int>();
            Random aRandom = new Random();
            RandomProportional aRandomProportinal = new RandomProportional();

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                int value = 0;
                do
                {
                    int indexChosen = aRandom.Next(4);
                    double xCoordinate = XCoordinateOfRandomUnitInsideSphere(aRandomProportinal);

                    if (aRandom.Next(2)==0)
                    {
                        xCoordinate = -xCoordinate;
                    }
                    double xRandomResult = xCoordinate * 64;
                    value = (int)(Input[indexChosen] + xRandomResult);
                } while (value < 1 || value > 64);
                sampleValues.Add((int)value);
            }
            sampleValues.Sort();
            Console.WriteLine();
            foreach (int i in sampleValues)
            {
                Console.Write(" {0:00} ", i);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }



        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestDistribution();
            Console.WriteLine("end");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: I've run some larger sets of data, and it is producing some anomalous results..   Namely too heavy clustering around [1](Not such an issue), and a significant drop off in hits around the middle of the range [17](A big issue). [link](http://imgur.com/a/ObHjP)

Comment: @tonyenkiducx have you tried with different values of concentrationAroundInputs, maybe from 1.0 to 5.0, to see if one of them  suits your needs a bit better?

Comment: If you have a look at the graph I linked too(Sorry, the link is not immediately obvious), there is a clear issue with the number 17.  I tried it just now with a value of 3 in the concentration, and then 2.  Both times 17 is about 50% less than the surrounding numbers, but I can't see an immediate reason why it would be?

Comment: I hope I don't seem ungrateful, your answer is definitely along the right lines!  Appreciate the help.

Comment: Not at all. The result is a bit tilted to the left. Use value = Convert.ToInt32(Input[indexChosen] + xRandomResult) instead of value = (int)(Input[indexChosen] + xRandomResult) so it rounds the value instead of truncate it.

Comment: [link](http://imgur.com/a/mt7Rd)  Beautiful!  Thanks for the help!  I think the rounding thing was throwing off my understanding of it, but it makes perfect sense now.  Now to part 2, making it work quickly for 70mil iterations ;)  I'll figure that one out on my own though. @xyq.384.b